# Cannot start a ChannelSftp channel connection to local apache sshd server (java)

Tags: java, sftp, jsch, channel, sshd

I am trying to test files arriving in an SFTP server. I set up a local sshd server using the following code

```
    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception{
        SshServer sshd = SshServer.setUpDefaultServer();
        sshd.setKeyPairProvider(new SimpleGeneratorHostKeyProvider());
        sshd.setPasswordAuthenticator(new PasswordAuthenticator() {
            public boolean authenticate(String username, String password, ServerSession session) {
                return true;
            }
        });
        sshd.setPort(22);
        sshd.setFileSystemFactory(new FileSystemFactory() {
            @Override
            public FileSystem createFileSystem(org.apache.sshd.common.session.Session session) throws IOException {
                return null;
            }
        });
        sshd.start();
    }
```

I use Jsch as a client to try and connect to this server. Unfortunately, whenever I try to call channel.connect(), I get **com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: failed to send channel request** exception. The code for the Jsch is shown below:

```
    public void testServer(){
        try{
            JSch jSch = new JSch();
            Session session = jSch.getSession("user", "localhost",22);
            Properties configTemp = new Properties();
            configTemp.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
            session.setConfig(configTemp);
            session.connect();
            ChannelSftp channel = (ChannelSftp)session.openChannel("sftp");
            channel.connect();
            if(channel.isConnected()){
                System.out.println("Connected");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Can anyone help with what I am doing wrong and how to fix this? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement a subsystem factory, like:

```
sshd.setSubsystemFactories(Collections.singletonList(new SftpSubsystemFactory()));
```

Comment: I am using sshd-core 2.3.0 and I dont think this is present in this version. If i use an older version, and implement the subsystem factory I get **Session.connect: java.io.IOException: End of IO Stream Read.** exception